# Can we provide notification to users using a pop up when opportunity records gets created from a trigger?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

Can we notify users using a pop up window when a opportunity is being created in backend through a trigger ? The popup should appear irrespective of which tab the user is in .

Comment: I don't think so. How about sending an email to the user. You may achieve that by a workflow.

Comment: Since mail is related to another app  . It would be difficult for user to keep tracking mails while they work in salesforce .  Business needs something within salesforce application to get notifications .

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options:

- The simple one (strongly recommended): in your trigger create a chatter post for that user. Browser (or mobile) notifications will take care of the popup. When browser notifications are integrated into the OS you even get them on OS level
- Add a Lightning control everywhere (lots of work) that subscribed to a platform event created in the trigger and then uses the lightning notification library
- Build a small Heroku app that listens to the platform events and then pushes a browser notification. Same effect as first option, it just doesn’t leave a trace

Guessing here: the chatter post look like what you want. It not only notifies, but also documents the fact. Now there are a few scenarios: notify an individual or a group. In the later case you need to subscribe your users to that group.

Hope that helps

Comment: another option: rest post to slack channel (user) and let slack handle the notifications; esp if org isn't using chatter

Comment: Even if an org isn’t actively using Chatter, it will still notify the user. No need for an extra external

Comment: hmm -- never thought of that - good point

Comment: @Sancool You are welcome. Feel free to accept the answer

Comment: Hi Stwissel ,
Thanks for solution ,but I do want to clarify about chatter post solution, 
even if the chatter post created  for the user /group , the user wont be getting notified through brower pop up  , it  just post in chatter tab and tags that user/group .( Tested from my side ) - Let me knw if there is any configuration setting need to be done to recieve pop up notification using chatter in sf 

The only way to get notification from chatter is by using external  chatter app (which is business is not keen as there are large number of users and installations would be overhead)

Comment: Popup works for directly to user and in Lightning